# Когда используется git revert?

Tags: git

Когда есть практический смысл использовать `git revert`?
Ведь он фиксирует отмену изменений и затем накладывает их на другие ветки, отменяя изменения в других ветках.

Comment: команда `revert` создаёт коммит(ы) в текущей ветке. о чём вопрос?

Comment: Помимо предыдущего комментария, полезность в истории. Кроме того, в *опубликованных* репозиториях *rebase* — очень плохая практика.